# JQuery Datatable is not showing all rows

Tags: jquery, datatable

I'm using version 1.10.19 of jQuery Datatables and I have a datatable which uses server-side processing/AJAX but it doesn't display all records. This is after I set the `paging: false` attribute. If I remove it, i.e. use paging it displays all records (but I don't want that).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#custtable').DataTable({
    scrollX: true,
    fixedHeader: true,
    orderCellsTop: true,
    searching: false,
    paging: false,
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": $.fn.dataTable.pipeline({
      url: '/Customer/GetCustomers'
    }),
  });
});
```

Here's the response from server:

```js
{
  "draw": 1,
  "recordsTotal": 2,
  "recordsFiltered": 2,
  "data": [
    ["1", "tt", "tt", "tt", "tt", "tt", "0", "0", "0", ""],
    ["1", "tt", "tt", "tt", "tt", "tt", "0", "0", "1234,5", ""]
  ]
}
```

Then it says "Showing 1 to 1 of 2 entries". Why doesn't it display all entries?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please add a [mcve] (preferable as [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)) that reproduces the problem with the data shown in your question as fixed data.

Comment: Side note: There isn't really any benefit in using `serverSide: true` if you want to display all the records at once.

Answer (score 0):

Use following line, hope so will solve your problem.

> "iDisplayLength": 100,